# Project Template with Blank Activity and Navigation type Scrollable Tabs + Swipe results in R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android

I updated my android ide (eclipse), and decided to try the new blank activity with scrollable tabs + swipe navigation.

When the template generates, out of the box - I get the error: "R cannot be resolved to a variable" for all my project resources. I have tried cleaning, fixing project properties, and I just can't get the R.java to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out there are MORE updates, even after the reboot AND I double checked to make sure.

I should have checked that other default projects weren't giving the same error, which they were.

Answer (score -2):

This is not really a problem. Close the ADT bundle and re-open it. It will set itself right and work.